# Coordinating/controlling multiple C applications

Tags: c, linux, shell, ipc

I was originally thinking of using pipes to coordinate and control multiple C applications with a shell script serving as the executive.  Let us say, a C application 'A' does X and another C application 'B' does Y. The shell script, by way of IPC with A and B detects that X and Y actions have been carried out. It then tells C application 'C' to do Z by way of IPC. The IPC mechanism here could be pipes. Is there a glue language that might be better at doing this - something that has low memory footprint on Linux? I am originally thinking of using a shell script to coordinate/control the C applications, suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Something like expect would work well.